# Laravel eager relationships empty query

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables : `hotels, hotels_data, hotels_types`

Table `hotels` have `id, type, stars`, etc... `type` field is set as foreign key referencing `type_id` in `hotels_types`. I'm managing to get the correct data from `hotels_data` but have an empty result on getting `hotels_types` title and I don't understand why.

The code is the following :

```
class Hotel extends Eloquent { 

    public function getList() {

        $data = Hotel::select('id','stars')->with('HotelData', 'HotelType')->paginate(10);

        return View::make('hotels.index')->with('hotels', $data);
    }

    public function HotelData()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('HotelsData')->select('id','hotel_id','title');
    }

    public function HotelType()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('HotelType','type_id', 'type')->select('id','type_id','title');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've obtained the desired result with the following:

```
Hotel::select('hotels.*','hotels_types.title as type')
    ->join('hotels_types', 'hotels.type', '=', 'hotels_types.type_id')
    ->with('HotelData');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong relationship for HotelType()

Your Hotel model should use the inverse of hasOne, which is belongsTo, because it contains the foreign key to HotelType (when a table contains a foreign key, it always belongs to the table being pointed to).

The following should work:

```
public function hotelType() {
  return $this->belongsTo('HotelType','type', 'type_id')->select('id','type_id','title');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I have tried this too before posting but still had null as result. I managed to find a solution using the leftJoin() helper and specifying the tables.columns instead of the above methods. It doesn't work (probably) with hasOne and belongsTo because there is no id column in types.table directly related to hotel.id

Comment: @Kyobul it's also worth noting that your relationship methods should be camelcase (HotelType() should be hotelType() and HotelData() should be hotelData()). Otherwise, calling $hotel->hotel_type will return null

Comment: Thank you Tony, taking note about it